# DigitalOcean - CloudFlare CDN & Self-Hosted CDN

Tags: networking, 16.04, server, vpn, nginx

I'm trying to decrease server response time as per Google PageSpeed Insights recommendation. They're saying "You should reduce your server response time under 200ms" and my server response time is approx 1.3 seconds. So I decide to make my own self-hosted CDN server by the guideline of [idiallo.com](http://idiallo.com/blog/creating-your-own-cdn-with-nginx).

But the question "**I'M ALREADY USING [CLOUDFLARE CDN](https://cloudflare.com/) (FREE PRODUCT)**".

> Do I need to close CloudFlare account?
>
> Can I setup my self-hosted CDN without stop using CloudFlare?

Thank you!